Run Docker with same user as on local host and own mounted folders
I have a local folder (code) on my system, which belongs to my user.
EDIT1: The folder structure is something like this (added this in response to a comment, not sure that's what the user was asking for):
- home
-- my_user
---- work
------ projects
-------- code

I want to run a Docker container and mount this folder in the container. I want this mounted folder to belong to the user I have on the local host, so I can access files, create them inside the container, and still own them on the local host.
Docker is running in rootless mode.
I'm using this Dockerfile:
FROM ubuntu

ARG UID
ARG GID
ARG USERNAME

# Install necessary packages including python3-virtualenv and pip
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    wget \
    python3 \
    python3-pip \
    python3-virtualenv \
    python3-dev \
    build-essential \
    git
RUN ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python && \
    ln -sf /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip

# Create a group with the specified GID
RUN groupadd -g ${GID} ${USERNAME}
# Create a user with the specified UID and GID (-d creates home folder, -s selects shell)
RUN useradd -d /home/${USERNAME} -u ${UID} -g ${GID} -s /bin/bash ${USERNAME}
# Add the user to the sudoers file
RUN echo "${USERNAME} ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
RUN mkdir /home/${USERNAME}/code && chown ${USERNAME} /home/${USERNAME}/code
RUN echo "${USERNAME}"
USER ${USERNAME}

I'm building the image with:
docker build --build-arg UID=$(id -u) --build-arg GID=$(id -g) --build-arg USERNAME=$(whoami) -t image_name -f Dockerfile .

And running it with:
docker run -it -v /home/my_user/work/projects/code/:/home/my_user/code image_name

Inside the container, my username, id and gid are the same as on the local host.
However, if I check the permissions, I see that the code folder still belongs to root:
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 10 root root 4096 Jul 11 14:41 code

I tried running chown again from the container:
chown -R my_user code/

but I get:
chown: changing ownership of 'code/xxx': Operation not permitted

for all the files in the code folder.

You may have your answer here: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/4540/how-to-change-the-owner-of-volume-directory-in-dockerfile

Please include the local folder listing outside of the container, and describe how docker is installed (running as root, rootless, snap, desktop, podman, etc).

Is there any particular reason to need Docker in this setup?  Your host system probably already has Python on it, and you don't seem to be installing anything beyond basic build tools in the image; can you just use your host Python (maybe using a tool like pyenv to manage multiple versions) and ignore Docker's complexities?

When running docker in rootless mode, all uid's and gid's are shifted into a different namespace, breaking volume bind mounts to host directory.
